# How to sort lines of a text file into an array of strings with many different cases

Tags: java

We have a text file with 10k+ entries that has these categories of information
year_film,year_ceremony,ceremony,category,name,film,winner
Here are a couple sample entries:

> 1936,1937,9,SPECIAL AWARD, The March of Time for its significance to motion pictures and for having revolutionized one of the most important branches of the industry - the newsreel.,,True
> 1937,1938,10,FILM EDITING,Bernard W. Burton,One Hundred Men and a Girl,False
> 2017,2018,90,WRITING (Original Screenplay),Screenplay by Guillermo del Toro & Vanessa Taylor; Story by Guillermo del Toro,The Shape of Water,False
> 2017,2018,90,SHORT FILM (Live Action),"Kevin Wilson, Jr.",My Nephew Emmett,False

We would like to read the file and put each category in a different index in an array of strings(i.e. all film years go into array index 0)
We thought it would be easy to just use string split by each comma, but there are too many irregular entries. We also thought we could just start writing cases but it seems like there are too many for that to be practical.
Here's what we tried already with splitting the string on the commas. Is there any type of different direction we could go or some way to deal with all the irregular cases?

```
BufferedReader reader;
        try {
            reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(
                    "D:/Downloads/cs131project/CSC131-main/simple-rest-apis-master/src/KaggleData_the_oscar_award.csv"));
            String line = reader.readLine();
            while (line != null) {

                String[] arrOfStr = line.split(",", -1);
                for (String a: arrOfStr) System.out.println(a);
                counter++;
                filmYear = arrOfStr[0];
                ceremonyYear = arrOfStr[1];
                ceremony = arrOfStr[2];
                category = arrOfStr[3];
                Name = arrOfStr[4];
                film = arrOfStr[5];
                winner = arrOfStr[6];
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "*irregular*"?

Comment: Quite honestly, this is why people invented RDBMS systems.  There are several relatively lightweight Java database systems you can use like a library.  Import this into the database (with any indexes you want) and then you can write queries against it for the results you want all day.  Don't reinvent the wheel. See: https://www.hsqldb.org, now in it's 20th anniversary release.

Comment: @PM77-1 What I mean by irregular is that many entries don't follow the base format of "year_film,year_ceremony,ceremony,category,name,film,winner". Some have multiple names, names with commas, and other things that don't allow a simple string split on comma. The examples I provided should be more clear on what they actually look like

Comment: @scottb hi, thanks for your suggestion! I'm taking another class that taught me the basics of SQL, would that be about the same as using HSQLDB? And would it be fairly simple to get all 10,000+ entries into the database in either SQL or HSQLDB?

Comment: @ midnightcoders: you can process the lines that follow the base format of "year_film,year_ceremony,ceremony,category,name,film,winner" with  a simple string split on comma and put other lines in new file. After that you can process new file

Comment: @midnightcoders: *" fairly simple to get all 10,000+ entries into the database in either SQL or HSQLDB?"* ... SQL is a specification for a relational database language.  HSQLDB is an implementation of that specification written in Java.  It is able to import CSV files.